# Simulate location from iOS app without Xcode

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, simulate

Is this possible? I want to simulate the locations given to other apps on the device.I know you can run Simulate location with Xcode  with a GPX track file, but I want to see if it can be done without Xcode. Any pointers would be appreciated. I see some apps on the AppStore which claims to do this, so it must be possible somehow.

Thanks